# How to list open ports in iOS?

Tags: ios, tcp, port, jailbreak

I am using a ***jailbroken** device and I want to **write an application** to list the open ports (e.g. TCP ports).

I have two ideas:

- Use some native API to get list of opened ports
- execute shell command to get a list of opened ports and parse the result of this shell command.

Which API or shell command should I use and how can I trigger it programmatically?

Comment: @Nate: You don't have to look any farther than the close reasons to find out what is off-topic here.  *"Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself.  Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved."*  To reiterate: **it is not sufficient that a question merely be about programming.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I would do this is to have your app invoke the UNIX `lsof` command programmatically.  `lsof` lists open "files", which on a BSD system includes sockets, which includes TCP sockets.

It used to be that Saurik published a version of `lsof` that was available on Cydia.  Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get that to work recently.  You might try it yourself, as software from Saurik should generally be trustworthy.  You could also try compiling the `lsof` source code yourself, as it's available online.

However, I found [a discussion thread about this here](http://modmyi.com/forums/native-iphone-ipod-touch-app-discussion/721184-lsof-problem.html).  User Firewire888 was able to get a homebuilt version of `lsof` working on iOS.  If you trust their work, then you can download the binary [file here](http://pupil.io8.org/pub/iphone/misc/lsof/lsof-arm7-iOS4.2).  Per their instructions:

> 1. On mac osx download ldid for macosx. https://networkpx.googlecode.com/files/ldid
> 2. On mac osx download [scaner's version of lsof in this thread](http://pupil.io8.org/pub/iphone/misc/lsof/lsof-arm7-iOS4.2). Thanks again!
> 3. On mac osx run `ldid -S lsof`
> 4. scp or whatever means get `lsof` to `/usr/sbin/lsof` on iPhone ( has to be in /usr/sbin otherwise get *error can't fork* )

So, you need to fake codesign that version of `lsof` and then install it on your iPhone at `/usr/sbin/lsof`.

Then, you can use the Private API `NSTask` (public on OS X) to run the shell command from within your app, and capture the output.

For example, using the command:

```sh
lsof -i4tcp
```

will list all IPv4 TCP ports.

In your Objective-C code, you'd do this:

```objc
#include "NSTask.h"

- (void) listTcpPorts {
   NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
   [task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/sbin/lsof"];
   [task setArguments: [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"-i4tcp", nil]];

   NSPipe *pipe= [NSPipe pipe];
   [task setStandardOutput: pipe];

   NSFileHandle *file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

   [task launch];

   NSData *data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

   NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSLog(@"tcp ports: \n %@", output);
}
```

This requires downloading the `NSTask` header, [which you can find here](https://github.com/rpetrich/iphoneheaders/blob/master/Foundation/NSTask.h).

which gave me the standard output:

```sh
Sep 11 18:53:47 iPhone5 HelloJB[34535] <Warning>: tcp ports: 
    COMMAND     PID   USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
    apsd        143 mobile    9u  IPv4 0x12345678      0t0  TCP 10.244.7.127:51216->17.172.238.202:5223 (ESTABLISHED)
    apsd        143 mobile   10u  IPv4 0x12345678      0t0  TCP 10.244.7.127:51215->17.149.37.18:5223 (ESTABLISHED)
    apsd        143 mobile   12u  IPv4 0x12345678      0t0  TCP 10.244.7.127:51215->17.149.37.18:5223 (ESTABLISHED)
    apsd        143 mobile   14u  IPv4 0x12345678      0t0  TCP 10.244.7.127:51216->17.172.238.202:5223 (ESTABLISHED)
    dataacces   166 mobile   25u  IPv4 0x12345678      0t0  TCP 10.244.7.127:51276->pc-in-f193.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
    dataacces   166 mobile   27u  IPv4 0x12345678      0t0  TCP 10.244.7.127:51276->pc-in-f193.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
    afcd      26764 mobile    9u  IPv4 0x12345678      0t0  TCP localhost:51284->localhost:51285 (ESTABLISHED)
    MobileSaf 33165 mobile   11u  IPv4 0x12345678      0t0  TCP 192.168.4.119:51349->stackoverflow.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
    MobileSaf 33165 mobile   12u  IPv4 0x12345678      0t0  TCP 192.168.4.119:51349->stackoverflow.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
    Weather   33191 mobile    5u  IPv4 0x12345678      0t0  TCP 192.168.4.119:50181->yts2.yql.vip.gq1.yahoo.com:http (LAST_ACK)
    Weather   33191 mobile    7u  IPv4 0x12345678      0t0  TCP 192.168.4.119:50182->yts2.yql.vip.gq1.yahoo.com:http (LAST_ACK)
    Weather   33191 mobile    8u  IPv4 0x12345678      0t0  TCP 192.168.4.119:50181->yts2.yql.vip.gq1.yahoo.com:http (LAST_ACK)
    Weather   33191 mobile   10u  IPv4 0x12345678      0t0  TCP 192.168.4.119:50182->yts2.yql.vip.gq1.yahoo.com:http (LAST_ACK)
    notificat 33929 mobile    4u  IPv4 0x12345678      0t0  TCP localhost:51295->localhost:51296 (ESTABLISHED)
    notificat 33929 mobile    5u  IPv4 0x12345678      0t0  TCP localhost:51301->localhost:51302 (ESTABLISHED)
    notificat 33929 mobile    6u  IPv4 0x12345678      0t0  TCP localhost:51318->localhost:51319 (ESTABLISHED)
    notificat 33929 mobile    7u  IPv4 0x12345678      0t0  TCP localhost:51330->localhost:51331 (ESTABLISHED)
    syslog_re 34468 mobile    3u  IPv4 0x12345678      0t0  TCP localhost:51321->localhost:51322 (ESTABLISHED)
```

You can choose to use different command line options, and/or parse the output, to suit your needs.  Good luck!

Comment: @frankish, using `sysctlbyname()` would be *another* strategy, but if you want to specifically ask about that, I would post another question.  Regarding the solution I gave you, your users won't have to download another binary.  For distributing via Cydia, you should make a Debian package.  The Debian package allows you to add files at the locations that they will be installed on the iPhone.  So, you can simply add a `/usr/sbin/lsof` binary file into your Debian package, and when users install your app via Cydia, Cydia (dpkg) will put `lsof` where it needs to be.  The user won't be bothered.

Comment: Also, if you really want to avoid installing `lsof`, you can find the `lsof` open source online.  Obviously, `lsof` code does whatever is necessary to list ports.  You can look through that code, and then figure out how it does the job.  Then, integrate that into your source code directly, and you don't need to use `NSTask` anymore.  But, I'm not going to describe that in detail, because that's **much** more work, and most people who view this question would probably prefer just to install the `lsof` binary as part of the app.

Comment: @frankish, you've **completely** changed the question since I originally answered it.  Stack Overflow is not a forum, where you keep posting comment after comment until you feel satisified.  You're supposed to post narrow, well-specified questions, one-at-a-time.  Vote for and accept answers that you find useful, and/or solve your problem.  Then, go on to a new, separate question.  Changing the requirements after I spent quite a bit of time, first to fight to get your question reopened (including arguing with moderators about it) and then to actually provide you a working solution, isn't cool.